# custom express.js mounting does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I have trouble implementing route mounting in express.js 4.13.3.

When I first install it, by default created in the `app.js`

```
var users = require('./routes/users');//get the "users" route
app.use('/users', users);//mount to "/users"
```

and the `users.js` route is like

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Does not need to define `router.get('/users'...` because mounting took care of that in the `app.js file`.

But

When I try to do the same thing

in `app.js` I set

```
var upload = require('./routes/upload');
app.get('/upload', upload);//mounting (?)
```

the `upload.js` route is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('upload', {title: 'Photo upload'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I access `localhost/users` I get 404 error. The only way to fix this , is to define in the `upload.js` router, this `router.get('/upload'` instead of this `router.get('/'`. But that would not be mounting.

The difference I see is that the default code uses `app.use('/users', users);` and my code uses `app.get('/upload', upload);`. Is the verb (use/get) the only difference that causes the 404? And if so, why? Or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are totally correct that the problem is caused because these to functions work differently. Below are the official API specifications for the functions.

[`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) is for mounting a middleware

[`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method) is for defining (only) one route for a HTTP GET request

This example shows a middleware function mounted on the /user/:id path. The function is executed for any type of HTTP request on the /user/:id path.

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});
```

This example shows a route and its handler function (middleware system). The function handles GET requests to the /user/:id path.

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('USER');
});
```